# Why ARCore is not supported Xiaomi Redmi Note 6 Pro?

Tags: android, 3d, arcore, xiaomi

Why ARCore is not supported Xiaomi Redmi Note 6 Pro ? Android 9.

Answer (score 0):

ARCore is Xiaomi has been supported from Redmi Note 7. Please check the below link of supported devices
[ARCore supported devices list](https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/supported-devices)